# unable build a regex for validating date

Tags: regex, validation, date, pattern-matching

I'm new to regex. I'm trying to build a regex for the following date pattern but unable to satisfy all the dependencies.

Here is the pattern I need to build.

```
21Jun
12Mar
31Aug
```

etc.

My problem is I'm unable to differentiate between the months that has 30 days and months with 31 days and particularly I don't want my regex to allow more than 28 days for the month of februari.

I have done some googling and found something like this:

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))
\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|
(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?
\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|
[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?
[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:
(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

But I'm unable to extract exactly what I want from that expression.

Comment: i dont need any validation for year as well...just ddMMM format without any hyphens or dots in the middle.thank you.

Comment: Without a year, you will not be able to validate Feb 29.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to keep the pattern simple:

```
/(\d+)(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)/
```

Then extract the 1st and 2nd matching groups (day and month), and then validate the day with respect to the month with code.

e.g.

```
if( month == "Feb")
   if( day > 28 )
      throw 'Invalid day for the month of February'
...
```

Comment: i can do that coding...but the requirement says that it should be build using regex.

Comment: Then, I guess @rosenheimer's solution is most suited to your needs!

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))|
((30)(Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))|
((31)(Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec))
```

Edit: This would allow February to have up to 28 days (and not allow 29Feb):

```
((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))|
((30|29)(Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))|
((31)(Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec))
```

Comment: That is as elegant as possible for a regex. But maybe a regex isn't the best solution here.

Comment: No, probably not=) The easiest solution would surely to break it up and use whichever native format for dates is present. No need for a regex first, if it's an invalid date it should give some kind of error when the date object is created.